# Ways to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2}\log \left( \frac{1}{n} +\tan^2x\right) dx$, as zero

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

When I've computed with Wolfram Alpha the definite integral $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\log \left( \frac{1}{n} +\tan^2x\right) dx,$$ (see the code *integrate log(1/n+tan^2(x))dx, from x=0 to x=pi/2*) then I said myself that should be very easy to get a result from this, since the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ of our RHS is zero. It is easy to see if we write it as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\pi \left( \log\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)+2\coth^  {-1}(\sqrt{n})\right) ,$$ and then we  calculate the limit of the second summand by using the definiton of the hyperbolic cotangent.

And now

> **Question.** Can you to prove by means different calculations and justifications that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2}\log \left( \frac{1}{n} +\tan^2x\right) dx=0?$$ Are required those calculations or hints in your claims and how you justify your claims. **Thanks.**

Comment: I don't know what can answer you! Sorry me @DanielFischer. If I have to choose one of the two, let it be Lebesgue.

Comment: Nice. The argument is much easier with Lebesgue.

Comment: Are you saying with a theorem from Lebesgue theory (dominated or monotone)? But my answer choosing Lebesgue was luck, this time @DanielFischer Any case, ify you or other user want add some remarks about the other case or ask a new question in MSE, are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need that $\log (\sin x)$ is Lebesgue integrable over $\bigl[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr]$. Since $\frac{2}{\pi}x \leqslant \sin x \leqslant 1$ on that interval, the integrability follows from that of $\log x$. Since $\cos x = \sin \bigl(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\bigr)$, the integrability of $\log (\cos x)$ is then clear. Next we note

$$\tan^2 x < \frac{1}{n} + \tan^2 x \leqslant 1 + \tan^2 x = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x},$$

and by the monotonicity of the logarithm

$$2\bigl(\log(\sin x) - \log (\cos x)\bigr) = \log (\tan^2 x) \leqslant \log \bigl(\tfrac{1}{n} + \tan^2 x\bigr) \leqslant -2\log (\cos x).$$

We thus have a pointwise convergent sequence of measurable functions sandwiched between two integrable functions, hence all these functions are integrable, and by the dominated convergence theorem

$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} \log \bigl(\tfrac{1}{n} + \tan^2 x)\,dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} \log (\tan^2 x)\,dx = 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \log (\sin x) - \log (\cos x)\,dx = 0$$

since

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \log (\cos x)\,dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} \log \bigl(\cos \bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{2} - u\bigr)\bigr)\,du = \int_0^{\pi/2} \log (\sin u)\,du.$$